# View home screen in iOS application (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, homescreen, translucency

How can I make the background of a UIView translucent so that the user can see their (blurred) home screen?

If this is not possible, perhaps I can screenshot the home screen and add a translucency effect. In this case, how do I take a screenshot of the user's home screen?

Apple has tight privacy views (which I support) so I understand that none of the above may be permitted.

Comment: i will answer your first question and say that it doesn't work after iOS 7

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. For having background of previous UIViewController, present next controller with presentationStyle as overFullScreen.

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If need translucent effect use,

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

#### 2. To take screenshot.

```
func takeScreenshot(view: UIView) -> UIImageView {
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
     view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
     let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
     return UIImageView(image: image)   
}
```

```
let view = HomeScreen().view
let image = taketakeScreenshot(view)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! However, Xcode is telling me `Use of unresolved identifier 'HomeScreen'`. Are there specific conditions for how to use `HomeScreen()`, or is this deprecated altogether?

Comment: @Benj, HomeScreen is a class whose screenshot I want. You can replace it with any class or direct UIView. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm sorry! I thought `HomeScreen` was an official API.